# Pyspark Shuffle Write size

Tags: apache-spark, hive, bigdata, pyspark

I am reading data from two sources at stage 2 and 3. As you can see, at stage 2, the input size is 2.8GB, 38.3GB for stage 3. But the Shuffle Write section for stage 2 is almost 10 times the input size, 23.9GB. Why, for stage 3, it is so much smaller comparing with its input size? It does not make any sense to me. I wonder why it is so large for stage2. Is it doing repartition given it only has 16 partitions on read?
[image]

Comment: Is your `spark.shuffle.compress` set to `true`, and is your `spark.io.compression.codec` same or "better" than input?

Comment: Yeah, **spark.shuffle.compress** is set to **True** and **spark.io.compression.codec** is the same. What do you mean "better" than input?